# What does it mean to surround a method reference with brackets?

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, java-8, method-reference

I'm using Java 8. I know it's new features like lambda, method references, etc. But I'm confused about this code:

```
static class SRoad implements Comparable<SRoad> {
    int id;

    public SRoad(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SRoad o) {
        return this.id - o.id;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<SRoad> c = new ArrayList<>();
    // Assume I added some instances in to the list...
    c.sort((SRoad::compareTo));
}
```

The code above basically sorts a list of SRoad according to it's id. Note that in the last line, the method reference is surrounded with an extra pair of brackets. This isn't a typo, it has to be like this for java to work. I found that this line of code is equivalent to:

```
c.sort(((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)));
```

Why are they equivalent? What's this grammar?

Comment: *This isn't a typo* - how do you know? have you tried otherwise?

Comment: The extra brackets are redundant.

Comment: This is a method reference and the extra brackets are not necessary

Comment: Sorry guys. I didn't try to remove the brackets. My bad. It's a redundant typo.

Comment: Some people think, brackets raise the clarity of the code. The more the better. Compare with `c.sort(((((((SRoad::compareTo)))))));`…

Comment: But generally, to sort a list of elements implementing `Comparable`, use `c.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());`. You could even use `c.sort(null);`, but then, the compiler won’t check whether the elements truly implement comparable. More important, you should never implement a comparison method using minus. The distance between two `int` values can be bigger than the `int` value range, leading to an overflow. Use `return Integer.compare(this.id, o.id);` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra set of parenthesis is redundant. You could just lose them:

```
c.sort(SRoad::compareTo);
```

Regarding the syntax -`sort` has a `Comparator` argument. This is a method that takes any two elements of the list you're sorting and compares them. Both ways pass such a method reference.